# Error Handling approaches for Stream Apps

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

How do people typically handle errors for stream applications?  In particular I'm using Spring Cloud Dataflow pipelines.  For example, in a typical source | processor | sink pipeline, if the processor step of a stream pipeline encounters an exception (for example, a remote service is unavailable for a REST request), do you typically let the exception bubble up and fall through to message queue error handling?  Or do you create a custom error output that you know to ignore in the sink?  Or some other approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to answer your question.

*Error handling* requirements are not technology driven. Business is the force behind it, so we first need to know what is your ***business requirement*** around error handling, only then we can discuss how a technology such as spring-cloud-stream can help you with it.